# Write to end of xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, append

I have an existing XML file below that I would like to write to using Java. I'm trying to add another pattern element with file and version-id within.  What I am doing is pulling the value of file and version-id from the last pattern element and then increasing the version numbers of those values.  I'm already successfully able to do that and set the new file and version values. I just now need to add them to the xml under a new pattern element.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp-versions>
      <resource>
        <pattern>
            <file>somejar_2_100_1_client.jar</file>
            <version-id>2.100.1</version-id>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <file>somejar_2_100_2_client.jar</file>
            <version-id>2.100.2</version-id>
        </pattern>
        <name>jarclient.jar</name>
       </resource>
    </jnlp-versions>
```

*****EDIT:

I used xPath to get the last resource Node. Once I got that I then appended a new pattern Node to it with my new file and version-id tags within.

```
Node resourceNode = (Node)xPath.evaluate("/jnlp-versions/resource[last()]",doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE);

    Element fileNode = doc.createElement("file");
    Element versionNode = doc.createElement("version-id");

    fileNode.setTextContent(newFileName);
    versionNode.setTextContent(newVersion);

    Element patternNode = doc.createElement("pattern");
    patternNode.appendChild(fileNode);
    patternNode.appendChild(versionNode);
    resourceNode.appendChild(patternNode);
```

Comment: Note that simply appending to an XML file won't give you a valid XML file, since you need to have exactly one root element. You'll need to read in the old one, make the changes, and write it back out, either streaming or by DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ok that is what I am currently doing

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) library and the [alises](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html) to map the XML to a java class and back. First, create a java class matching the XML, e.g.:

```
class JnlpVersions {
  Resource resource;
}

class Resource {
 String name;
 Set<Pattern> patterns;
}

class Pattern {
  String file;
  String versionId;
}
```

Then load the existing xml file into an instance of the `JnlpVersion`. Fetch its `resource` and add to it a new `Pattern`. Then, using XStream save the instance to a new xml file.